# How to clear Gradle Jar "archiveFile doesn't have a configured value" error

Tags: java, gradle, jar

I'm in the process of upgrading a project from Gradle 4.4 to Gradle 7.6. There's a Jar task that used to work but now fails. The task definition:

```
task createSpocClasspath(type: Jar) {
    def libDir = distLibsDir
    inputs.dir libDir
    outputs.file "$libDir/spoc-classpath.jar"

    doFirst {
        manifest {
            // The sort is important as it makes the Java 7 jars come
            // before the Java 8 jars, which is needed to compile
            // MATLAB binaries that depend on SPOC Java code.
            attributes "Class-Path": libDir.listFiles({file -> file.getPath().endsWith(".jar") } as FileFilter).sort().name.join(" ")
        }
        destinationDir = libDir
        baseName = 'spoc-classpath'
    }
}
```

This results in the following error message:

```
> Task :code:createSpocClasspath FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':code:createSpocClasspath' (type 'Jar').
  - Type 'org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar' property 'archiveFile' doesn't have a configured value.
    
    Reason: This property isn't marked as optional and no value has been configured.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Assign a value to 'archiveFile'.
      2. Mark property 'archiveFile' as optional.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/validation_problems.html#value_not_set for more details about this problem.
```

I've read the Gradle documentation for Jar tasks, and [this Stack Overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69893762/gradle-set-archivefile-of-a-custom-jar), but somehow I can't find the correct syntax to get this Jar task back on track.

Any assistance would be most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it was a scoping issue. The Jar task definition was in a scope in which the Java plugin hadn't been applied. Once I addressed that, the problem resolved itself.